# How to delete an azure website completely

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How do I delete an azure website so that all the ftp settings are removed.

I'd like to delete the website, and re-create it fresh but when I do it seems to get the settings from the previous one?

I've tried using the portal and powershell to remove it.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I'm looking to delete my azure website and all it's settings so I can re-create it as if it was new, not do just do a clean deployment.

Thanks

Comment: have you tested my proposed solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you delete a site (e.g. via portal), there will be nothing left of it, and no settings will remain if you recreate a site.

If you think you are seeing some things persist, please be more specific about what. 'settings' could refer to many different things.

Comment: Hi David, The FTP settings seem to persist if I delete the site and re-create it with the same name

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the 'FTP settings'? If you mean the host name (e.g. `ftp://waws-prod-db3-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net`), then it is normal for it to be the same. But the publishing (aka site) credentials will be different. And if you are referring to the deployment (aka user) credentials, those are per user and not per site, so they will of course not change.

Comment: See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials for an explanation on Site vs User credentials, which may help clarify things.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that in many ways.

- Delete it from the portal
- Delete it using Azure CLI
- Delete it using using powershell

The first of them doesn't need much more explanation, go to the portal and just delete it.

Delete it using CLI is easy, and you will want to recreate it.

### Prepare the [Azure CLI](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9828653&clcid=0x409)

If you aren't friendly using the CLI maybe you need to prepare the login and mode

```
azure config mode arm
azure login
```

The last command output something like this, just visit the URL and use the code.

```
info:    Executing command login
/info:    To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://aka.ms/devicelogin. Enter the code THECODE_XYZ to authenticate. If you're signing in as an Azure AD application, use the --username and --password parameters.
```

This is the *normal* flow, if you have multiple subscriptions may be you will need to run few commands more to select the right one.

### Delete the webapp

```sh
azure webapp  delete --name mysitename --resource-group MyREsourceGroup --quiet
```

You'll need to have the **site name** and the **resource group** you'd like to use.

### Create the webapp again

```
azure webapp create -g MyREsourceGroup -n mysitename -l EastUs -p "My-WebPlan"
```

Note that the site creation in this sample is located in **East US Region**
You'll need to have the **site name** and the **resource group** you'd like to use, and the **web plan**

---

That's all, you can create a bat file to execute this each time you need to. Additionally you can configure many other options in the website .

This demo was using Azure ARM mode, you can also create the site using ASM (*classical mode without resource group things* but some other features not yet available in ARM mode command prompt)

Answer (score 1):

If you use visual studio to publish, when you right click and select publish, in the Settings tab there is this Publish options that you can check:

"Remove additional files at destination" which will do a clean deployment for you:

[image]